# Generate data from azure data lake store

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, azure-data-lake

I am new to Scala and spark i would like to load the files from azure data lake store.
I want to load all the files which start from test.

I tried as follows:

```
folder/test[0-10000]*.csv"
```

Can some suggest any solution?

Comment: add some more details to your question.